# More Advanced JQL for Swimlanes and Fixversions on Sprint Board

Tags: jira, jql

I get by with basic understanding of Jira and JQL for the most part, but I would like to streamline a process.

Everytime I add a new fixversion I also have to add a new swimlane to our sprint board. I was hoping I could eliminate this by using a more advanced JQL query.

Instead of:

```
fixversion = 3.0.0
```

Use something like:

```
fixversion = "Current Sprint" AND is OPEN
```

The results should be that I never need to add new swimlanes when I open new fixversions, and only show fixversions that are still opened. I should also be able to display multiple versions in a sprint if that condition exists as well.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
sprint in openSprints ()
```

Only available if you are using JIRA Agile 6.6
**Documentation:**
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver073/advanced-searching-functions-reference-861257222.html?_ga=2.141919090.1302349630.1507452194-702843776.1505580610#AdvancedSearchingFunctions-openSprints()

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up trying out the following:

fixVersion in unreleasedVersions(ANDROID) AND sprint in openSprints()

The problem I ran into is that we usually have multiple fixVersions in a sprint. This didn't create multiple swimlanes for each.

Comment: When using _JQL_ you must remember it is not like _SQL_, JIRA API converts your _JQL_ request to JavaScript expressions to fit their API. What i wanted to say is : JQL is quite limited in what it can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ScriptRunner you could use `earliestUnreleasedVersionByReleaseDate()`.

See: https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html